DC Offset of a single-ended OTA
I'm confused by the concept of DC offset voltage. According to this application note by TI, DC offset seems to be the result of the asymmetry (Vth, bias current, etc.) - they only consider the 'differential offset'. What about the common-mode offset, like in a simple 5T OTA without mismatch, if the output common-mode voltage (Vocm) is not precisely controlled to 0V, there'll also be a 'offset' voltage.
Does this also count as DC offset? Or we simply use fully differential configuration and set the output common-mode voltage to 0 when we don't want common-mode offset?


The input offset voltage (VOS) is defined as the voltage that must be
applied between the two input terminals of the op amp to obtain zero
volts at the output.
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa059b/sloa059b.pdf?ts=1717650448395

So it's only DC and only finds the voltage to obtain true zero, it does not include CMRR which is show as a different source in the schematic in the document.

For example in this circuit - https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=c75c92h8r637  VIN1 has to be much smaller than VREF for VOUT to be close to zero. Does this mean that VOS is very large?

It would be whatever voltage difference between In- and In+ to get out to go to zero. They also have circuits to measure this with one opamp driving another and then measuring Vos
